# SQL selecting concentration of holding in a portfolio

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a schema made up of 2 tables, `clients` and `holdings`. `holdings` contains portfolio holdings of a certain client on a certain date.

**clients**

```
id int AUTO_INCREMENT   PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(30)
```

**Holdings**

```
id int AUTO_INCREMENT   PRIMARY KEY,
client_id int,
holding varchar(80),
value decimal(6,2),
holding_date DATE
```

How get I select the proportion that a particular holding makes up of its client's portfolio on that date?

E.g. if client 1 has 3 holdings (holding 1, 2, 3) in their portfolio on 2014-11-30 worth 80, 80 and 40 respectively then they would make up  40%, 40% and 20% respectively. The issue I'm having is getting the divisor, which is the sum of all the holdings of a certain client on a certain date. I presume a subquery is needed but I'm having trouble forming it.

I have tried something like

```
SELECT clients.name, holdings.name, sum(holdings.value) / (SELECT sum(holdings.value) WHERE holdings.date = '2014-11-30' AND ...) -- how do I get the conditions in the subquery
FROM clients LEFT JOIN holdings ON holdings.id = holdings.client_id
WHERE holdings.date = '2014-11-30'
GROUP BY clients.name, holdings.name
```

I've made a sqlfiddle to help visualize the scenario and populated it with sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2083d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the data and join the result back in.  In your case, you want to do this with a correlated subquery that would look like this:

```
SELECT c.name, h.name,
       sum(h.value) / (SELECT nullif(sum(h2.value), 0)
                       FROM holdings h2
                       WHERE h2.date = h.date AND
                             h2.client_id = h.client_id
                      ) -- how do I get the conditions in the subquery
FROM clients c LEFT JOIN
     holdings h
     ON c.id = h.client_id
WHERE h.date = '2014-11-30'
GROUP BY c.name, h.name;
```

I also fixed the join between `clients` and `holdings`.  The `on` condition should mention both tables.

In the event that the value of a holding could be zero, I added the `NULLIF()` function to prevent divide-by-zero.

Comment: Do I need to alias the table names? How does `h.*` and `h2.*` work?

Comment: @harryg . . . You need to alias the table names.  That is what `h` and `h2` are.